# /apple-precomposed.png 404 requests

Tags: android, html, ios, favicon

Im getting /apple-precomposed.png 404 errors. I already read that its related to icons, etc., but everywhere it says :

```
apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
apple-touch-icon.png
```

why do I get

```
apple-precomposed.png
```

? I need this so I could create those icons, but confused how to name them?

I looked at the user strings and all of them are Linux Android, not iOS.

Also Im getting 404 for:

```
/apple
```

What this can be?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `apple-precomposed.png` is not an "official" name and no browser should look for such file.

You should check your HTML code, especially if you didn't write it yourself (eg. web site template, WordPress theme...). Maybe it explicitly mentions this file. Something like:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-precomposed.png">
```

Comment: hi, I didnt write anything related to apple and no, its not wordpress, its my custom code that I know throughout. Most of them from Samsung mobiles or tablets, maybe that will give a hint.

Comment: Android devices do use the Apple icons. Yet they don't invent their own rules, which appear to be the case here. I admit I'm a bit clueless...